# XML Digital Signature validation

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, verify, xml-signature

I was trying to validate an XML signature.

The validation according to this [tutorial](http://www.j2ee.me/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/XMLDigitalSignatureAPI8.html) works fine.

But I also tried to a second approach. To verify it with the [verify method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify%28byte[]%29) of the Signature class 
I extracted the signature and the certificate from the xml file, and I did the following:

```
    public static boolean checkSignedFile(byte[] data, byte[] sigToVerify,
        byte[] cert, String algorithm) throws CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Certificate c = (Certificate) cf
            .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert));
    PublicKey pk = c.getPublicKey();
    Signature sig;
    boolean verifies = false;
    sig = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
    sig.initVerify(pk);
    sig.update(data);
    verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
    return verifies;
}
```

the result was false. The signature did not verify. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: The tutorial link does not seem te be working anymore.

Comment: This is probably the new one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't verify XMLDsig like this. It wouldn't work. The signature is not calculated over the raw XML. It has to go through canonicalization, digest etc.

What do you use for `data[]`? To get it right, you almost have to rewrite the XMLDsig library.

Comment: the data[] is actually the file that is signed. I have checked it has the same digest as the digest in the xml signature. So the digests are the same. And that's why I am curious why the verification does not work

Comment: So the file is XMLDsig signed XML file? Then you would have the signature inside the file, right? Would it be a chicken-egg issue if you can just verify the whole file :)

Comment: I know is a bit late now... but how do you use the digest?

Answer (score 0):

If data[] is the content of the signed XML file, what is sigToVerify?

XMLSig creates a Signature-Element (SignedInfo) that contains the digest of each Element to be signed and meta-information like used canonicalization/transformation algorithms. Then the digest of this SignedInfo-Elemnt is calculated and signed.

Hence, if sigToVerify is the signature created by a XMLSignature implementation it must not be equal to the signature of the complete XML file.

[Here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/08/xmldsig.html#xml-sig) is a more complete explanation. And if your interested, take a look at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/).